# JFace Action and ImageDescriptor - I wnt to show image and text

Tags: java, jface

```
Action myAction= new Action("LABEL", ImageCache.getImageDescriptor("IMAGE"));
```

This code shows me a button without any text. Instead it only shows the image. 
What should I do to display them both side by side? 
I tried using  `setText()` and `setDescription()` and `setImageDescriptor()` but none helped.

Comment: Where are you using this action?

Comment: I'm adding it to a ToolBarManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text is not normally shown for an action in a `ToolBar` if there is also an image.

If you are adding the `Action` to the tool bar manager using an `ActionContributionItem` you can call `ActionContributionItem.setMode(ActionContributionItem.MODE_FORCE_TEXT);`

Comment: The image is appearing before the text. How can I make it appear after the text?

Comment: I don't think you can. If the ToolBar has the SWT.RIGHT style then text is drawn to the right of the image, without this style the text is drawn below the image.